# Applying for multiple EU residence visas in different countries

Tags: visa, residency

I have heard that if you are applying for multiple Schengen/tourist visas in multiple EU countries within a short period of time it may be considered as "visa shopping".

How about applying for multiple **residence** visas in more than one EU country at the same time (applications just a few weeks apart)? Any problem with that?

Comment: Could you give an example of how this would arise? I am thinking of Germany's job seeker visa. If another country has something similar then I don't think it would be unreasonable to apply in both countries. Other common reasons for applying, like family reunion, or employment, won't usually present this problem.

Comment: @user16259 I doing a visa application for self-employment in Portugal and another one in Germany at the respective consulates of those countries.

Comment: Not a direct answer, but consider just applying to the country which offers you the best business prospects and then make use of the free trade zone to sell your services to customers in both countries.